# Disable Wireless on a Cisco EPC3925?

Tags: wireless-router, dsl-modem

I can't seem to turn off the Wireless Network on a Cisco EPC3925 modem/router. I can set Wireless to disabled in the "Wireless" tab of the web interface, but the wireless network remains.
There's also an option to disable it from the Setup/Quick Setup tab, but if I click the disable button there and then "Save settings", nothing seems to have changed and the form has reset itself to the initial values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out only the internet service provider (Ziggo) was able to turn off the wireless for me remotely.
I guess they put custom firmware on their modem routers to prevent customers from being… difficult? I imagine they have more problems with people complaining about a lack of wifi, than people wanting it gone.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/video/at_home/Cable_Modems/3900_Series/4021192_B.pdf) on page 39, going into the Wireless Basic Settings you can disable/enable wireless from there. Maybe turning the wireless configuration to "Manual" would help with the problem too.

Comment: I already put the Wireless Configuration to Manual—makes no difference. And like I said, disabling it in the Wireless tab doesn't actually disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Un-check the "Show key", this helped me.